# How would I abstract Command/Response in an extensible way?

Tags: haskell

While trying to do some domain driven design in Haskell, I found myself with this problem:

```
data FetchAccessories = FetchAccessories
data AccessoriesResponse = AccessoriesResponse

data FetchProducts = FetchProducts
data ProductsResponse = ProductsResponse

type AccessoryHandler = FetchAccessories -> AccessoriesResponse
type ProductHandler = FetchProducts -> ProductsResponse

handle :: Handler -- Not sure how to do this abstraction
handle FetchAccessories = AccessoriesResponse
handle FetchProducts = ProductsResponse

someFn :: AccessoriesResponse  -- Ideally
someFn = handle FetchAccessories
```

What I'd like to do is tie together a single Fetch* with a single Response*, and give enough information so that the compiler knows if I call `handle FetchAccessories`, it can only return `AccessoriesResponse`.

#### Edit:

Even more ideally, this would work without annotation, products & accessories having their appropriate type inferred:

```
biggerFn =
  let products = handle FetchProducts
      accessories = handle FetchAccessories
  in
    undefined -- do business things
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated, this is exactly the job for type classes. Type class is a construct that lets you tie together a few types, as well as define some functions on those types.

In your case we can define the a class `Handler` like this:

```
class Handler request response where
    handle :: request -> response
```

Here, `request` and `response` are type variables, representing two types, which get "tied together" by our class, and a function `handle` that takes one and returns the other.

Next, we can define instances of this class for your two cases:

```
instance Handler FetchAccessories AccessoriesResponse where
    handle FetchAccessories = AccessoriesResponse

instance Handler FetchProducts ProductsResponse where
    handle FetchProducts = ProductsResponse
```

And then we can use the function:

```
someFn :: AccessoriesResponse
someFn = handle FetchAccessories
```

(note that you'll need to enable `MultiParamTypeClasses` for this to work)

---

**In response to your comment:** *I wonder if there is some way to avoid the annotation on someFn (since ghc seems so very close to knowing)*

The problem is, GHC is not actually close to knowing. *You* know that `AccessoriesResponse` only goes with `FetchAccessories`, but as far as GHC is concerned, that's not necessarily true. After all, you could very well go ahead and add another class instance like this:

```
instance Handler FetchAccessories String where
    handler FetchAccessories = "foo"
```

And now it turns out that `handle FetchAccessories` might mean either `AccessoriesResponse` or `"foo"`. GHC cannot decide for you.

But you can tell it, explicitly, that for every request type there can be only one response type. This is called "functional dependency" (you need to enable `FunctionalDependencies` for this), and the syntax is the following:

```
class Handler request response | request -> response where
    handler :: request -> response
```

This will tell GHC that `response` is uniquely determined by `request` and will have two practical consequences: (1) GHC will reject the second instance `Handler FetchAccessories String` from my example above, complaining that it violates the functional dependency, and (2) GHC will be able to figure out what `response` is just by knowing `request`.

In particular, this means that you can omit the type signature on `someFn`.

On a related note, you may or may not also want to do the opposite thing: for every response there can be only one request. To do that, you can specify *two* functional dependencies:

```
class Handler request response | request -> response, response -> request where
```

---

**(the below is no longer relevant in light of your comment, but I'll leave it here for the record)**

However, I *suspect* that what you actually meant was a different kind of model. What I suspect you meant is a model that says "*a request can be either for products or for accessories, and a response can be either that of products or of accessories, and the `handle` function would turn any given request into a corresponding response*"

If that is what you indeed meant, the suitable model would be sum types:

```
data Fetch = FetchAccessories | FetchProducts
data Response = AccessoriesResponse | ProductsResponse

handle :: Fetch -> Response
handle FetchAccessories = AccessoriesResponse
handle FetchProducts = ProductsResponse
```

Comment: I meant the type class approach, as what I'd like to avoid is any request can return any response.  This is really close to what I'm looking for, but I wonder if there is some way to avoid the annotation on someFn (since ghc seems so very close to knowing).

Comment: I have just updated the answer, please check it out

Comment: That is incredibly cool, I didn't know of functional dependencies.  Thank you so much, it's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Wouldn't a functional dependency (or even two) help things out here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @dfeuer. The answer does talk about functional dependencies. Or did you mean in some other sense?

Comment: No, I just missed that part. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closed set of fetches, this may also be a natural use case for a GADT, indexed by a tag that indicates the type of request or response.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Tag = Accessories | Products

data Fetch (t :: Tag) where
  FetchAccessories :: Fetch 'Accessories
  FetchProducts :: Fetch 'Products

deriving instance Show (Fetch t)

data Response (t :: Tag) where
  AccessoriesResponse :: Response 'Accessories
  ProductsResponse :: Response 'Products

deriving instance Show (Response t)

type Handler t = Fetch t -> Response t

-- Handles any type of request.
handle :: Handler t
handle FetchAccessories = AccessoriesResponse
handle FetchProducts = ProductsResponse

-- Handles only accessory requests.
-- The compiler knows this matching is exhaustive.
handleAccessories :: Handler 'Accessories
handleAccessories FetchAccessories = AccessoriesResponse

someFn :: Response 'Accessories
someFn = handle FetchAccessories
```

You may of course add more fields to the `Fetch` and `Response` types.

```
data Fetch (t :: Tag) where
  FetchAccessories :: AccessoryName -> Fetch 'Accessories
  FetchProducts :: ProductId -> Fetch 'Products
```